# Filter matching cases from different datasets in R

Tags: r, filter

I have a few time-series datasets, e.g., GDP growth, FDI and education over the period 1960-2000. Identifying (unique) variable in all datasets is `country_name`. Some countries are present in one dataset but missing in another. I would like to select (filter) the countries that are present in all datasets. How this can be done in `R`?
`data.frame`'s look as follows:

```
FDI
country       2001        2002       2003        2004       2005
   A    -0.4769080 -0.89159864 -0.2140591 -0.93326470 -0.1726757
   B    -0.1246048  0.09929738  1.0522747  0.08724465 -0.9064532
   C     1.9592917  1.06080273  0.5316807 -0.94478259 -1.1342767
   E    -1.0585177  0.58981906  0.5210434 -0.81212231  0.7862898

GDP growth
country       2001        2002       2003       2004        2005
   A    0.06323898  0.08537586  0.8982821 -1.3635704  0.45569153
   B    1.19848687  1.41307212  0.3358561 -0.8368255  0.22987821
   D    1.13491209 -0.98472341  0.7545730 -0.3595143  0.07172593
   E    0.83561289  0.51227238 -0.1377516  1.8841489 -0.94319505
```

I need to select matching cases A, B and E, and put everything in long format, preferably using `reshape2`.
Output should look like (excluding C and D because they are not in both datasets):

```
country    year      FDI            GDP growth
  A        2001   -0.4769080        0.06323898
  A        2002   -0.89159864       0.08537586
  A        2003   -0.2140591        0.8982821
  ... ...
  B        2001   -0.1246048        1.19848687
  ... ...
  ... ...
  E        2005    0.7862898       -0.94319505
```

Comment: You need to include a reproducible example.

Comment: Added an example @nrussell

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Added how output should look like. I do not get it why the question got downvoted.

Comment: @MoazzemHossen, I would assume that the downvote was because you showed no effort of trying to solve your problem. People tend to get annoyed sometimes by that. - Needless to say I am not the downvoter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first create an index variable with the common countries between the data frames and we use `melt` from `reshape2` package to convert to long format. Finally, we merge `by` the first two columns

```
library(reshape2)
ind <- intersect(FDI$country, GDP_Growth$country)
d1 <- melt(FDI[FDI$country %in% ind,], id.vars = 'country')
d2 <- melt(GDP_Growth[GDP_Growth$country %in% ind,], id.vars = 'country')
new.df <- merge(d1, d2, by = c('country', 'variable'))
head(new.df)
#    country variable    value.x     value.y
#1       A    X2001 -0.4769080  0.06323898
#2       A    X2002 -0.8915986  0.08537586
#3       A    X2003 -0.2140591  0.89828210
#4       A    X2004 -0.9332647 -1.36357040
#5       A    X2005 -0.1726757  0.45569153
#6       B    X2001 -0.1246048  1.19848687
```

Comment: Thanks! I am pretty new to R and did not know about the `intersect` function. I can figure a way out now.